# Python - Select clicável

Tags: python

Eu tenho que exibir na tela (Tkinter) uma lista puxada do banco de dados (mysql) contendo informações sobre uma pessoa (nome e id) e tornar possível que qualquer item dessa lista possa ser clicável e, ao clicar em algum, selecione o id dessa pessoa e chame outra função em seguida. Como fazer isso em Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código abaixo usa `sqlalchemy` para criar uma tabela no banco de dados e inserir nomes aleatórios, depois usa `tkinter` pra mostrar uma lista desses nomes, e ao clicar exibe o nome selecionado.

[image: Screenshot do programa]

```
BANCO_DE_DADOS = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/nomedobanco'

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import Column, Unicode, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmsg

Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker()

class Pessoa(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pessoas'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(Unicode(300))

def inicializa_banco(engine):
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.create_all()
    Session.configure(bind=engine)

def cria_pessoas_de_teste(num_pessoas=10):
    import random
    import itertools
    nomes = ['Bruno', 'Cláudio', 'Alfredo', 'João']
    sobrenomes = ['Costa', 'Almeida', 'Souza', 'Teixeira']
    nomes_completos = [' '.join(g) for g in itertools.product(nomes, sobrenomes)]
    for n in random.sample(nomes_completos, num_pessoas):
        yield Pessoa(nome=n)

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.combo()

    def combo(self):
        self.box_value = tk.StringVar()
        self.box = tk.Listbox(self.parent)
        self.box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.selecionou)
        s = Session()
        for p in s.query(Pessoa):
            self.box.insert(tk.END, '{0.id} - {0.nome}'.format(p))
        s.close()
        self.box.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def selecionou(self, evt):
        pos = int(self.box.curselection()[0])
        pessoa = self.box.get(pos)
        tkmsg.showinfo(title='Selecionado!', message='Você selecionou {}'.format(pessoa))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine(BANCO_DE_DADOS, echo=True)
    inicializa_banco(engine)
    s = Session()
    s.add_all(cria_pessoas_de_teste())
    s.commit()
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Lembrando que, pra funcionar, você tem que editar a linha com o nome do banco, usuário e senha.

Comment: Note que o código usa python 3, se quiser usar python 2 tem que trocar `import tkinter as tk` por `import Tkinter as tk` e `import tkinter.messagebox as tkmsg` por `import tkMessageBox as tkmsg`

Answer (score 0):

Algumas considerações iniviais, sem levar em conta que você já se decidiu por usar o tkinter: se for um problema real para ser resolvido, e não um exercício de aprendizado, primeiro você tem que optar que tecnologia usar para a interface do seu programa: pode ser um aplicativo desktop, que abre uma janela local própria, ou pode ser uma aplicação web.

No segundo caso, o seu programa é executado, e fica rodando de fundo, mas não cria nada na tela diretamente. Um navegador Web no mesmo computador aponta para uma porta no próprio computador, disponibilizada pelo framework usado pelo seu programa - e tudo o que o seu programa tem que fornecer é HTML bem formatado, com elementos de link `<a ...>` para outra função de view que pode fornecer os detalhes.

Pode assustar se você nunca fez nada parecido, mas essa é a maneira mais fácil - mesmo por que depois de pronto, as pessoas podem usar seu programa a partir de outros computadores na mesma rede, ou mesmo na Internet, sem precisar instalar nada localmente.

Eu sugeriria o uso do micro-framework Flask - faça o tutorial, e verá que é simples chegar onde você quer: https://flask-ptbr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

A outra forma que mencionei, com uma aplicação direta, exige o uso de uma biblioteca com um toolkit gráfico - que pode ser o tkinter, que vem instalado com o próprio Python.

A sua simplicidade inicial pode esconder muitos problemas inerentes do desenvolvimento de interfaces gráficas, que o HTML resolve bem, separando a lógica da apresentação - em HTML você cria m documento simples, e depois pode arrumar o layout com CSS, sem se preocupar com a lógica do seu programa. A começar de que mesmo que você faça um tutorial legal de tkinter ou outro toolkit como GTK+ ou Qt, dificilmente o tutorial cobrirá exemplos de uso em conjunto com um banco de dados, e como ter elementos de dados clicáveis na tela.

A propósito, a maior parte dos tutoriais e documentação do tkinter e outras bibliotecas gráficas sofre de um vício que complica bastante o desenvolvimento: todos insistem em criar seu programa como uma classe que herda diretamente da classe de Janela ou outra equivalente do toolkit gráfico. Isso é desnecessário - seu programa *tem* uma janela, não é uma janela - é perfeitamente possível escrever isso sem o uso de classes criadas pelo usuário.

Comece criado uma função principal que cria a janela e os componentes desejados (como frames, botões de navegação, etc) como variáveis normais. Eu sugiro o uso da biblioteca externa complementar "ttk" que tem o widget "treeview" - sem ele você terá que re-inventar a roda pra fazer uma lista de elementos clicáveis com barra de rolagem:  https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

Em suma, não é impossível fazer em tkinter - mas também não tenho como criar o programa do zero pra você nessa resposta.  Se optar por isso, por favor comece o seu código criando o esqueleto da janela, layout desejado com o uso de frames, etc... e eu ou mais alguém aqui poderá dar mais dicas.